# Spring boot 2 database mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping, hql

i have the following scenario and i wanna know is someone knows how to solve it, it is as follows:

I'm tasked with remakign an old application, and the naming of attributes was really confusing, because it had all things in plural so you can't know by getter and setter name if anything is an object or a list of objects. So one thing i did was changing property names but maintaining @column(name="x") with the name of the column.

The problem is that my applion is mapping when making the query with hql (i'm using jpaRepository from spring data jpa) using the getter and setters and not the column name, is there a way to override the mapping making it use column name and not getter and setters? Or to have two getters and setters of the same attribute one for mapping and one for codding?

Thanks in advance.-

Comment: If you put the @Column on the attribute and not on the getter JPA uses this.

Comment: So, i should use the @column on the getter and not the attribute so it overrides the mapping?

Comment: no you should use the @Column on the attribute. And the you can name the attribute whatever you like without changing the getter/setter

Comment: That is how it is already done, all my annotations are on the attribute, not getter or setter. 
But for example the attribute id of an entity was named idMovimiento,
when i left the @Column(name="idmovimiento")
and getter getId.
The exception threw: There is no column with name id on the entity name

Comment: Ah and you want id. Then you have to put the annotatoins on the getter